# Rename unique row values in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, row, rename

I am still quite fresh to `R`, but still I couldn't work around this.
What I would like is to take unique row value, and rename it.

```
  Name    X        Y
1 Var_1 23.57755 35.50492
2 Var_2 23.57769 35.48199
3 Var_1 23.57865 35.50202 
4 Var_1a 23.57883 35.50120
5 Var_2 23.57932 35.50197
6 Var_1a 23.58040 35.50050
```

This is part of my code, and I would like to take row name `Var_1a` for instance, and rename it to `Var_1`.

I have several of unique values that need to be renamed, and reason is that it is species occurrence data, and some records have old scientific names, and I want for them to be all the same according to the latest taxonomy.

Furthermore, I tried using `row.names()`, however I get the row ID (numbers) as row names, and part of my problem is not knowing how to get the `row.names()` function to read from the "Name" column. Also will it make a problem since new row will have duplicate name as old row name?!?

Thank you.

Comment: Use of `row.names`/`rownames` attributes and functions is usually discouraged. In this case, you can probably do `DF$Name <- sub("[a-z]$", "", DF$Name)` or similar.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!